# How to properly read and write to array of string in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I want to create an array of strings in C. ( I know C doesn't include a concept like string. I mean char * as saying string)

I read from a txt file word by word. Than put it in the array of strings than try to access this array of strings again.

Here is my code

```
char x[MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];
char** wordsInDocument;
int wordCount = 1;
/*M defined as 997 which is max word count in a file*/
wordsInDocument = malloc(M * sizeof(char*));
int i = 0;
/* MAX_WORD_LENGTH defined as 200 */
while (fscanf(f, " %200s", &x) == 1) {
    wordsInDocument[i] = malloc((MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(char));
    wordsInDocument[i] = x;
    printf("Here wordCount : %d i : %d x : %s wordsIndocument : %s [0]th element : %s  \n",wordCount, i,&x ,wordsInDocument[i],wordsInDocument[0]);
    wordCount++;
    i++;
}

wordsInDocument = realloc(wordsInDocument, (wordCount ) * sizeof(char*));


for (i = 0; i < wordCount-1; i++) {
    printf("WordsInDocument [%d] = %s\n",i, wordsInDocument[i]);
}
```

My function reads from a file word by word. There is no problem here. But I can't put in "wordInDocument" array proper way. Because of that first element always be the last element which read from file.

Here is some CMD outputs to show what I mean.

```
Here wordCount : 1 i : 0 x : ballpark wordsIndocument : ballpark [0]th element : ballpark
Here wordCount : 2 i : 1 x : figure wordsIndocument : figure [0]th element : figure
Here wordCount : 3 i : 2 x : enterprise wordsIndocument : enterprise [0]th element : enterprise
Here wordCount : 4 i : 3 x : milestone wordsIndocument : milestone [0]th element : milestone
Here wordCount : 5 i : 4 x : stack wordsIndocument : stack [0]th element : stack
Here wordCount : 6 i : 5 x : vertical wordsIndocument : vertical [0]th element : vertical
Here wordCount : 7 i : 6 x : platform wordsIndocument : platform [0]th element : platform
Here wordCount : 8 i : 7 x : agile wordsIndocument : agile [0]th element : agile
Here wordCount : 9 i : 8 x : workflow wordsIndocument : workflow [0]th element : workflow
Here wordCount : 10 i : 9 x : core wordsIndocument : core [0]th element : core
Here wordCount : 11 i : 10 x : competency wordsIndocument : competency [0]th element : competency
Here wordCount : 12 i : 11 x : stand-up wordsIndocument : stand-up [0]th element : stand-up
Here wordCount : 13 i : 12 x : market wordsIndocument : market [0]th element : market
Here wordCount : 14 i : 13 x : focus wordsIndocument : focus [0]th element : focus
Here wordCount : 15 i : 14 x : standard wordsIndocument : standard [0]th element : standard
Here wordCount : 16 i : 15 x : setter wordsIndocument : setter [0]th element : setter
Here wordCount : 17 i : 16 x : industry wordsIndocument : industry [0]th element : industry
Here wordCount : 18 i : 17 x : leader wordsIndocument : leader [0]th element : leader
Here wordCount : 19 i : 18 x : deliverable wordsIndocument : deliverable [0]th element : deliverable
Here wordCount : 20 i : 19 x : game wordsIndocument : game [0]th element : game 
Here wordCount : 21 i : 20 x : changer wordsIndocument : changer [0]th element : changer
Here wordCount : 22 i : 21 x : brand wordsIndocument : brand [0]th element : brand
Here wordCount : 23 i : 22 x : organic wordsIndocument : organic [0]th element : organic
Here wordCount : 24 i : 23 x : growth wordsIndocument : growth [0]th element : growth
Here wordCount : 25 i : 24 x : alignment wordsIndocument : alignment [0]th element : alignment
Here wordCount : 26 i : 25 x : best wordsIndocument : best [0]th element : best 
Here wordCount : 27 i : 26 x : practice wordsIndocument : practice [0]th element : practice
Here wordCount : 28 i : 27 x : standpoint wordsIndocument : standpoint [0]th element : standpoint
Here wordCount : 29 i : 28 x : bandwidth wordsIndocument : bandwidth [0]th element : bandwidth
Here wordCount : 30 i : 29 x : emerging wordsIndocument : emerging [0]th element : emerging
Here wordCount : 31 i : 30 x : market wordsIndocument : market [0]th element : market
Here wordCount : 32 i : 31 x : architecture wordsIndocument : architecture [0]th element : architecture
Here wordCount : 33 i : 32 x : big wordsIndocument : big [0]th element : big
Here wordCount : 34 i : 33 x : data wordsIndocument : data [0]th element : data 
Here wordCount : 35 i : 34 x : enterprise wordsIndocument : enterprise [0]th element : enterprise
Here wordCount : 36 i : 35 x : stakeholder wordsIndocument : stakeholder [0]th element : stakeholder
Here wordCount : 37 i : 36 x : user wordsIndocument : user [0]th element : user 
Here wordCount : 38 i : 37 x : experience wordsIndocument : experience [0]th element : experience
Here wordCount : 39 i : 38 x : diversity wordsIndocument : diversity [0]th element : diversity
Here wordCount : 40 i : 39 x : driver wordsIndocument : driver [0]th element : driver
Here wordCount : 41 i : 40 x : cloud wordsIndocument : cloud [0]th element : cloud
Here wordCount : 42 i : 41 x : proposition wordsIndocument : proposition [0]th element : proposition
Here wordCount : 43 i : 42 x : low wordsIndocument : low [0]th element : low
Here wordCount : 44 i : 43 x : hanging wordsIndocument : hanging [0]th element : hanging
Here wordCount : 45 i : 44 x : fruit wordsIndocument : fruit [0]th element : fruit
Here wordCount : 46 i : 45 x : silo wordsIndocument : silo [0]th element : silo 
Here wordCount : 47 i : 46 x : prince2 wordsIndocument : prince2 [0]th element : prince2
Here wordCount : 48 i : 47 x : practitioner wordsIndocument : practitioner [0]th element : practitioner
Here wordCount : 49 i : 48 x : step-change wordsIndocument : step-change [0]th element : step-change
Here wordCount : 50 i : 49 x : core wordsIndocument : core [0]th element : core 
Here wordCount : 51 i : 50 x : asset wordsIndocument : asset [0]th element : asset
Here wordCount : 52 i : 51 x : synergy wordsIndocument : synergy [0]th element : synergy
Here wordCount : 53 i : 52 x : action wordsIndocument : action [0]th element : action
Here wordCount : 54 i : 53 x : point wordsIndocument : point [0]th element : point
Here wordCount : 55 i : 54 x : capability wordsIndocument : capability [0]th element : capability
Here wordCount : 56 i : 55 x : team wordsIndocument : team [0]th element : team 
Here wordCount : 57 i : 56 x : player wordsIndocument : player [0]th element : player
Here wordCount : 58 i : 57 x : paradigm wordsIndocument : paradigm [0]th element : paradigm
Here wordCount : 59 i : 58 x : shift wordsIndocument : shift [0]th element : shift
```

I get the above output from this line:

```
printf("Here wordCount : %d i : %d x : %s wordsIndocument : %s [0]th element : %s  \n",wordCount, i,&x ,wordsInDocument[i],wordsInDocument[0]);
```

As you can see function can get current word without a problem. But it always show as the first element. Example at line 57 it writes this.

```
Here wordCount : 57 i : 56 x : player wordsIndocument : player [0]th element : player
```

But it should write

```
Here wordCount : 57 i : 56 x : player wordsIndocument : player [0]th element : ballpark
```

Because first word is "ballpark".

Because of that when I try to run this lines of code :

```
for (i = 0; i < wordCount-1; i++) {
printf("WordsInDocument [%d] = %s\n",i, wordsInDocument[i]);
}
```

I get "shift" always. Because "shift" is the last word in current document.

I suspect this line :

```
wordsInDocument[i] = x;
```

But I couldn't fix it. Could anyone help me with this please ?

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. Instead of `wordsInDocument[i] = x;` you should use `strcpy()` here.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Actually I tried it a few times before asking here but when you mention it again I look up to all code again and I realized I didn't write -1 to wordCount in for loop when I was trying strcpy(). This is the way it throws Exception before. Now it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this line to :

```
wordsInDocument[i] = x;
```

To this line :

```
strcpy(wordsInDocument[i], x);
```

And it works now. Thanks Johnny Mopp for fast answer.